# How to manage which variable/instance variable to use for API Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, memory-management, code-readability

I have 2 way of code but I don't know which one is better for memory.

```
def create
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  address = nil
  user.transaction do
    address = user.address.create!(params[:address_params])
  end
  render json: user, address
end
```

or

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.transaction do
    @address = user.address.create!(params[:address_params])
  end
  render json: @user, @address
end
```

in this case I would choose second one.
But my colleague concern that the first one is memory optimal choice in case of callback like after_action @instance_variable wont return the memory until after_action finished

so I want to which one is better and how. Thank you
ps. sorry for my bad english if my wording/code is not clear I will fix it

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb is one does not create instance variables and uses local variables *unless* the variable is to be reused from within another method (which is nowadays is arguably considered to be not the best practice.)

Anyway, if your code is going to reuse the variable, it is the instance variable, because local variables will be garbage collected *after the method returns* and *are not reachable from outside of the scope in general*.

That said the following code works:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @bar = 42
  end
  def calc
    @bar / 2
  end
end
Foo.new.calc
```

while the following one raises:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    bar = 42
  end
  def calc
    bar / 2
  end
end
Foo.new.calc
```

It has a very little if none impact on memory consumption, though. Instance variables are never the bottleneck (unless it’s gigabytes of course) and garbage collection is not promised to happen immediately after the scope was left for local variables as well.

Comment: so in small scope even variable got mix up practically has little to no impact to memory

so from my understanding
```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.transaction do
    @address = user.address.create!(params[:address_params])
  end
  render json: @user, @address
end
```